# Django command "django-admin startmyproject" not working?

Tags: python, django

The above mentioned command is not working.
Showing the result after giving command -
No Django settings specified.
Unknown command: 'startmyproject'. Did you mean startproject?
Type 'django-admin help' for usage.

Comment: It is `django-admin startproject`, without the `my`. This is even written in the error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command should be startproject. Also, have u defined a django settings file for ur django installation. Try out the steps in this documentation to make this work correctly.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown command: 'startmyproject'. Did you mean startproject?

The result is pretty self-explanatory, no such command exist. It's `django-admin startproject`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run this `django-admin startproject 'your peoject name goes here'`
This should be just after activating virtual and installing django